# Reading user Data for iOS application

Tags: ios, swift

I want my iOS Application reading data from a specific path like:

`/Users/you/Desktop/test.zip` (around 4GB)

but it throw an error saying that `File do not exitsts`. So what can I do to make my iOS Application can read data from that path? Basically I don't want to drag and drop `test.zip` into my project because it will also be built with my project everytime i run

Comment: That makes no sense. How should the iPhone access a file on your macOS Desktop?

Comment: Provide the code that you have wrote to access this file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use FileManager with .documentDirectory. But maybe!!!

Answer (score 0):

you need to put file in project directory and i think it will not be copied every time you build the project. It is copied just once until you delete and copy it again in project directory.